# On surjective operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $T$ is a surjective bounded linear operator on $\mathcal{H}$. Suppose that $\mathcal{K}$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{H}$ such that $T|_{\mathcal{K}}$ is surjective. Does the relation $T^*\mathcal{H} \leq \mathcal{K}$ hold?

My attempt: Suppose that $h\in \mathcal{H}$. There are elements and $h_1\in \mathcal{K}$ and $h_2\in T^*\mathcal{H}$ such that $$Th_1=h=Th_2.$$ Thus $h_1-h_2\in \ker T$ and $h_1= (h_1-h_2)+h_2$ which yields that $T^*\mathcal{H} \leq \mathcal{K}$.

Is this argument correct?

Comment: Not really. Why is $T|_{T^*\mathcal H}$ surjective onto $\mathcal H$? Why would $\mathcal K$ contain $\ker T$? (or how do you reach the conclusion?)

Comment: @Berci Since $\mathcal{H}= T^*\mathcal{H} \oplus \ker T$, the operator $T|_{T^*\mathcal{H}}$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$, then define $T$ by 
$$
Te_n=\begin{cases}
e_k,&\ n=2k\\ 
e_k,&\ n=2k-1
\end{cases}
$$
Let $K=\operatorname{span}\{e_{2k}:\ k\in\mathbb N\}$. Then $T|_K$ is surjective. We have 
$$
\langle T^*e_k,e_{2j}\rangle=\langle e_k,Te_{2j}\rangle=\langle e_k,e_j\rangle=\delta_{k,j}=\langle e_{2k-1}+e_{2k},e_{2j}\rangle,
$$
and
$$
\langle T^*e_k,e_{2j-1}\rangle=\langle e_k,Te_{2j-1}\rangle=\langle e_k,e_j\rangle=\delta_{k,j}=\langle e_{2k-1}+e_{2k},e_{2j-1}\rangle,
$$
so
$$
T^*e_k=e_{2k-1}+e_{2k}.
$$
In particular, $T^*e_1=e_1+e_2\not\in K$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a subspace $\mathcal{K}'$ of $\mathcal{H}$  which is contained in the every subspace $\mathcal{K}$ such that $T|_{\mathcal{K}}$ is surjective?

Comment: No. In the exsmple, $K'=\{0\} $.